# It sould be so obvious, but why does this fail?

Tags: c#, .net

Been coding .net for years now yet I feel like a n00b. Why is the following code failing?

```
byte[] a = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray(); // 16 bytes in array
string b = new UTF8Encoding().GetString(a);
byte[] c = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(b);
Guid d = new Guid(c);    // Throws exception (32 bytes recived from c)
```

**Update**

Approved the answer from CodeInChaos. Reason for the 16 bytes becomming 32 bytes can be read in his answer. Also stated in the answer:

> the default constructor of
>   UTF8Encoding has error checking
>   disabled

IMHO the UTF8 encoder should throw exception when trying to encode a byte array to string that contains invalid bytes. To make the .net framework behave properly the code should have been written as follows

```
 byte[] a = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();
 string b = new UTF8Encoding(false, true).GetString(a);  // Throws exception as expected
 byte[] c = new UTF8Encoding(false, true).GetBytes(b);
 Guid d = new Guid(c);
```

Comment: Thank you for getting rid of `var`. It's as if the entire point of `var` is to hide errors. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not every sequence of bytes is a valid UTF-8 encoded string.

The GUID can contain almost any sequence of bytes. But UTF-8 as specific rules for which byte sequences are allowed if the value is >127. And a Guid will quite often not follow these rules.

Then when you encode the corrupted string back to a byte array you get a byte array longer than 16 bytes, which the constructor of Guid doesn't accept.

---

The documentation on UTF8Encoding.GetString states:

> With error detection, an invalid sequence causes this method to throw a ArgumentException. Without error detection, invalid sequences are ignored, and no exception is thrown.

and the default constructor of UTF8Encoding has error checking disabled(don't ask me why).

> This constructor creates an instance that does not provide a Unicode byte order mark and does not throw an exception when an invalid encoding is detected.
>   **Note**
>   For security reasons, your applications are recommended to enable error detection by using the constructor that accepts a throwOnInvalidBytes parameter and setting that parameter to true.

---

You might want to use Base64 encoding instead of UTF-8. That way you can map any valid byte sequence into a string and back.

Comment: Then why does the framework not throw an exception when receiving a string it cannot UTF8 encode?

Comment: No idea why they designed their API like that. IMO silently ignoring encoding errors by default is stupid.

Answer (score 3):

To encode arbitrary byte data as a string you should use base-64, hex, etc. You cannot assume that random set of bytes makes a valid UTF* (or other encoding) string.

http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2010/03/binary-data-and-strings.html

Answer (score 0):

Because `var b` is type `string`, which means it's a unicode string (2 bytes per character).  In your second line, you're creating a 16-character string out of a 16-byte array, but that 16-character string is stored in 32 bytes.

Why not just do this:

```
var d = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Comment: Obviously the string `b` will be transmitted or stored and then decoded elsewhere. That the decoding happens directly afterwards is only because this is simple sample code demonstrating the problem.