# Why am i getting gibberish instead of hash value?

Tags: c#, hash, md5

Here is my little helper method to get the hash value from a string. But i am getting some sort of strange text instead of hash value :

```
 public static string GetHashValue(string sourceString)
        {
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceString)));
        }
```

I don't think the value i get from this function is really a hash value.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Well what do you get when you print it as output? If you get something that only contains the letters A to F and digits 0 to 9, yeah, that's the hash value.

Comment: the hash is in bytes, are you trying to convert it to string representation?

Comment: @BoltClock :- I am not getting letters A to F and digits 0 to 9 which is why this question exists from my side. I am getting ??4??yEm3???.

Comment: @Kar Cheng: hmmm, IIRC you should not do `GetString()` like that.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769682/it-sould-be-so-obvious-but-why-does-this-fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be expecting this to be displayed as a Hexidecimal string.  That's a common representation, and would differ from what you're displaying now.  For details, see [the MSDN sample](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307020).

Try the following changes to your code (adapted from the above sample):

```
 public static string GetHashValue(string sourceString)
 {
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
    byte[] hashData = provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceString));

    int i;
    StringBuilder sOutput = new StringBuilder(hashData.Length);
    for (i=0; i < hashData.Length; ++i)
    {
        sOutput.Append(hashData[i].ToString("X2"));
    }
    return sOutput.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: - In hurry you have forgotten to increment i. Please see your loop. But it's alright!

Answer (score 2):

Using UTF8.GetString() doesn't make sense here, the hashing function doesn't return a string encoded in utf-8.  It's just a byte[] with arbitrary byte values.  Use Convert.ToBase64String() instead.  It is still gobbledygook but it is supposed to be.  It's hashed.  You can roundtrip it back to byte[] with Convert.FromBase64String().