# Why is using UTF-8 for encoding during deserialization better than ASCII?

Tags: c#, encoding, deserialization

I want to deserialize a JSON file – which represents a RESTful web service response – into the corresponding classes. I was using
 `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ResponseString)` and I read on the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.asciiencoding.getbytes?view=netframework-4.8) that using UTF-8 encoding instead of ASCII is better for security reasons.

Now I am a little confused because I don't know the real difference between these two (**regarding the security thing**). Can anyone show me what the real practical advantages of using UTF-8 over ASCII for deserialization are?

Comment: Why were you using `ASCII.GetBytes` at all? You don't need that to deserialize JSON (or any other format), you need a JSON serializer like Json.NET or System.Text.Json. You *can't* use `ASCII` if the text contains *any* character outside the 7-bit US-ASCII range. Any character outside that range will be replaced with a `?` `Any Unicode character greater than U+007F is translated to an ASCII question mark ("?").`

Comment: As for security reasons - imagine if your super strong password was replaced with `?????`

Comment: thanks a lot!, of course I am using a Json serializer, sorry for not mention it, my interests are what are the security risks that I am taking by using ASCII!, anway thanks to your comment, now I have an Idea about the security thing!, like if I used the ASCII encoding I would risk of missreading some charcters from the Response?, that the ASCII can't read?

Comment: @Marios ASCII can describe 128 unique code-points; UTF-8 can describe 1.1M unique code points. So... ASCII can handle 0.015% of the possible values. OK, in reality the distribution isn't uniform, but... you get the point.

Comment: @MarcGravell Now I get it, Thaks a lot!, In the matter of fact this means that it's embarrassing to use ASCII to encode this type of data in our time!

Comment: @Marios if you use a deserializer there's no reason to use `GetBytes` at all. Deserializers work with the strings themselves

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos actually I am using a serializer object from `DataContractJsonSerializer` and then I am taking a `MemoryStream` like that: `using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString)))`

Comment: anyway I edited the code, and I changed the `ASCII` encoding.

Comment: @Boann You are tottaly right!, thanks for re-editing the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ultimately, the intention of an encoder is to get back the data you were meant to get. ASCII only defines a tiny tiny 7-bit range of values; anything over that *isn't handled*, and you could get back garbage - or `?`, from payloads that include *e̵v̷e̴n̸ ̷r̵e̸m̵o̸t̸e̵l̶y̸ ̶i̴n̴t̵e̵r̷e̵s̶t̶i̷n̷g̵ ̶t̸e̵x̵t̵*.

Now; what happens when your application gets data it can't handle? We don't know, and it could indeed quite possibly cause a security problem when you get payloads you can't handle.

It is also just frankly embarrassing in this connected world if you can't correctly store and display the names etc of your customers (or print their name backwards because of right-to-left markers). Most people in the world use things outside of ASCII on a daily basis.

Since UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII, and UTF-8 basically won the encoding war: you might as well just use UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Since not every sequence of bytes is a valid encoded string vulnerabilities arise from unwanted transformations which can be exploited by clever attackers.

Let me cite from a black hat whitepaper on [Unicode security](https://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-09/WEBER/BHUSA09-Weber-UnicodeSecurityPreview-PAPER.pdf):

> Character encodings and the Unicode standard are also exposed to
>   vulnerability. ... often they’re related to implementation in
>   practical use. ... the following categories can enable vulnerability
>   in applications which are not built to prevent the relevant attacks:
>
> - Visual Spoofing 
> - Best-fit mappings
> - Charset transcodings and character mappings
> - Normalization
> - Canonicalization of overlong UTF-8
> - Over-consumption
> - Character substitution
> - Character deletion
> - Casing
> - Buffer overflows
> - Controlling Syntax
> - Charset mismatches
>
> Consider the following ... example.  In the case of U+017F LATIN SMALL
>   LETTER LONG S, the upper casing and normalization operations transform
>   the character into a completely different value.  In some situations,
>   this behavior could be exploited to create cross-site scripting or
>   other attack scenarios
>
> ... software vulnerabilities arise when best-fit mappings occur. To name a
>   few:
>
> - Best-fit mappings are not reversible, so data is irrevocably lost.
> - Characters can be manipulated to bypass string handling filters, such as cross-site scripting (XSS) filters, WAF's, and IDS devices.
> - Characters can be manipulated to abuse logic in software. Such as when the characters can be used to access files on the file system. In
>     this case, a best-fit mapping to characters such as ../ or file://
>     could be damaging.

If you are actually storing binary data [consider base64 or hex instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4769714/8291949).

Comment: Thanks for you efforts!, practically talking and after you pointed it out, it's so clear to me that using ASCII for encoding this type data is kind of naive and so much risky!.